# Clojurescript serialize form AJAX POST

Tags: ajax, forms, clojure, clojurescript, luminus

## Serialize a form in Clojurescript

I'm submitting a simple, small form via Clojurescript (received by my Clojure/Luminus server). If I simply submit the form with a submit button, I can see the response includes a section like this:

```
:form-params {__anti-forgery-token TDsE55j9y7d1dT2eWOGnmECMnnNXWo5tIDVzENc9lr1aiJSqOKIVmmmq/XmaC2M6GHN086+VeROwi7up, app-type professorial}
```

But when I post it with CLJS-Ajax, I see this:

```
; ...
:body #object[java.io.ByteArrayInputStream 0x23bbfd9d java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@23bbfd9d]
:form-params {}
; ...
```

So the form is being put into a ByteArrayInputStream once it hits the server, apparently. The ajax/clojurescript code looks like this:

```
(defn submit-update-form []
  (let [form (.getElementById js/document "userform")
        url "/update-user"
        csrf-token (.-value (.getElementById js/document "token"))]
    (.log js/console form)
    (POST url {:handler #(js/alert "Submission!")
               :content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
               :body form
               :headers {:x-csrf-token csrf-token}})
    ;(.submit form)
    false))
```

Clearly I would need somehow to put the serialized form contents into the :form-params of the post. How can this be done?

My handler code as I try to get this up and running is dead simple:

```
(POST "/update-user" req
    (println req))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the correct type in your post's `:body` value.

In your example, you put the DOM object of the form id'd by *userform* as the `:body` value although you specified that the content-type of the body of your ajax post is *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* kind-of string.

You could use google closure's `goog.dom.forms.getFormDataString`. You can find the docstring of that function here https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/namespace_goog_dom_forms.html#getFormDataString

the modified code snippet of your `POST` call with form serialization:

```
;; (:require [goog.dom.forms :as gforms]) ;; require it first and alias it to gforms

(POST url {:handler      #(js/alert "Submission!")
           :content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
           :body         (gforms/getFormDataString form)
           :headers      {:x-csrf-token csrf-token}})
```

Comment: I've tried this, but my server is still recording the same request: content-type application/transit+json, form-params {} and a ByteArrayInputStream as the body. This is with Luminus' default middle-ware.

Comment: could you post your handler code for "/update-user"?

Comment: Done; it just prints the request.